# When I access my site from domain name images are not showing

Tags: apache, dns, xampp

I am hosting my website on XAMPP on windows server
When I access it from the ip like `123.45.67.89/mywebsite` the images load correctly but when I access it from `subdomain.domain.com` it loads but the images in website are not loaded
error in browser was `example.jpeg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: Does your browser console have any errors in it? Can you see exactly what urls it is trying to load? What do the src attributes on your image tags look like?

Comment: yes sorry I forgot to write that
`1500581792_p.jpeg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`